# What's the equivalent of cin.ignore() in C?

Tags: c++, c, stdin, cin, stdio

I understand that C++ stream functions are built on top of C's `stdio` library.

What do I have to do in C to get the same result as `cin.ignore(n)`?
For example, should I use `stdio` function `fseek(stdin, n, 0)` or is there some other method that `cin.ignore` is using?

Comment: No, C++ stream functions are not build on top of C's `stdio` library. There is no equivalent to `ignore()` in C. You have to do it yourself, read using `getc()` one character at a time until you've read the terminating character, encounter `EOF`, or read the specified number of characters.

Comment: You understood bad.  C++ streams functions are built on their own.  Where did you get that assumption?

Comment: @LuisColorado, read the answer to the question. There you can see that `cin.ignore` calls `getc` under the hood.

Comment: @Getfree, that's not warranted, implementations can do otherwise, they can be based completely in new implementations.

Comment: @LuisColorado, I'm not talking about what the standard guarantees, but what happens in practice. `iostream` implementations (not all) are built on top of `stdio`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is not. But let's look what happens behind the curtain called `cin.ignore()`. Let's take [llvm libcxx sources](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx), I find them faster to look through then gcc's.

The [extern istream cin;](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/master/include/iostream) is in iostream, but it is initialized on application startup in [iostream.cpp](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/master/src/iostream.cpp) using statically allocated buffer and __stdoutbuf object constructed from the good' old' `FILE *` `stdin`:

```
_ALIGNAS_TYPE (istream) char cin [sizeof(istream)];
ios_base::Init::Init()  {
    istream* cin_ptr  = ::new(cin)  istream(::new(__cin)  __stdinbuf <char>(stdin) );
    ...
```

The `istream::ignore()` function can be found in [istraem](https://github.com/google/libcxx/blob/master/include/istream#L1125). It's pretty simple, first we check if the user wants to clean all chars from the stream or just some of them (`if (__n == numeric_limits<streamsize>::max())`). Then the function calls `this->rdbuf()->sbumpc()` in a loop predefined amount of counts (or endless, in case `__n` is equal to `numeric_limits<steramsize::max()`). We can find `sbumpc()` to be a member of `std::basic_streambuf`, from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf/sbumpc):

```
int_type sbumpc();
Reads one character and advances the input sequence by one character.

If the input sequence read position is not available, returns uflow(). Otherwise returns Traits::to_int_type(*gptr()).
```

So we can simply deduce that `this->rdbuf()` returns handle to `__stdinbuf<char>(stdin)`. In the `cin::ignore` function the call to `__stdinbuf<char>(stdin)::sbumpc()` is made that many times, as many characters we want to ignore. So let's go to `sbumpc()`! First let's take a look at [streambuf](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/streambuf#L187):

```
int_type sbumpc() {
    if (__ninp_ == __einp_)
        return uflow();
    return traits_type::to_int_type(*__ninp_++);
}
```

So `if (__ninp_ == __einp_)` is doing some internal buffering in `streambuf` object, not to call `uflow()` if there are already buffered characters in our buffer. `__ninp__` pointer get's incremented after each read, that must be it. `uflow()` is overloaded by `__stdinbuf : public basic_streambuf< .... >`, from [__std_stream](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__std_stream#L100):

```
template <class _CharT>
typename __stdinbuf<_CharT>::int_type
__stdinbuf<_CharT>::uflow()
{
    return __getchar(true);
}
```

Puff, let's go to `__getchar` and find out what the `true` parameter is. It's right below in [__std_stream](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/__std_stream#L107).
It's a long function, with the main functionality, which takes care of some buffering. But we can spot the hearth of this function right away:

```
template <class _CharT>
typename __stdinbuf<_CharT>::int_type
__stdinbuf<_CharT>::__getchar(bool __consume) {
    ....
        int __c = getc(__file_);
        if (__c == EOF)
            return traits_type::eof();
    ...
}
```

Let's go from the beginning:

- `cin` is an `istraem` object and is initialized from `__stdinbuf<char>(stdin)`
- `istream::ignore()` calls `basic_streambuf::sbumpc()` predefined number of times, probably on an object initalized using `stdin`
- `basic_streambuf::sbumpc()` takes care of some bufering and calls basic_streambuf::`uflow()` if the buffer is empty.
- `basic_streambuf::uflow()` is overloaded by `__stdinbuf::uflos()` and calls `__stdinbuf::__getchar()`
- `__sinbuf::__getchar()` calls `getc(__file__)` so probably `getc(stdin)` to read one character from the stream

To sumarize:

```
void stdin_ignore(size_t n, int delim)
{
    while (n--) {
        const int c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF)
           break;
        if (delim != EOF && delim == c) {
           break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Aditionally

```
scanf("%*[^\n]\n"); // Ignores a line
```

or

```
scanf("%*s"); // Ignores one string
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since this question was posted, but this solution seems to be portable between Linux, Mac OS and Windows (including MSVC).  If you are trying to get the user to enter a number, and they accidentally enter something like 123a45, any numeric or string/char input request after that will just be skipped because "a45" will still be in the stdin 'buffer'.  To fix this, take a look at this example:

```
char someCString[64];
const int LENGTHOFCSTRING = 64;
fgets(someCString, LENGTHOFCSTRING, stdin);
```

This reads all of the data (up to 64 characters) from stdin, including '\n', and places it into the someCString array.  As mentioned earlier, you could also create a function (stdin_ignore) which does this one character at a time with no limits on the length of the C-String.